# Javascript: delete members of a json array

Tags: javascript, json

My server application (Node.js) returns to the front-end the users list (array of json). But I dont want to return also some fileds such as the password. So this is my user model code:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var config = require('../../config.js');

module.exports = mongoose.model(config.DATA_TYPE.USER, new Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    admin: { type: Boolean, default: false},
    rate: { type: Number, default: 0},
    customers: { type: Number, default: 0},
    registration: { type: Date, default: Date.now}
}));
```

I'm trying by the manager to don't forward also some fields but without positive results. This is how I try to delete few members of the user's objects of the array:

```
var _ = require('lodash');
var User = require('../models/user.js');
var config = require('../../config.js');

var Manager = { 
    getUsers: function(callback){
        User.find({ admin : "false"}, function(err,users){
            for (i in users){
                delete users[i].admin;
                delete users[i].password;

                delete users[i]._id;
                delete users[i].__v;
            }
            callback(err,users);
        });
    },
```

The front-end receive all fields (no filter is applied).
If I use a different way for hiding the data, for example:

```
    users[i].password = "xxx";
    users[i]._id = "xxx";
    users[i].__v = "xxx";
    users[i].admin = "xxx";
```

instead of the `delete users[i].password` etc... it is not hiding the `_id` and `__v` members, while `password` field is correctly hidden to the front-end (`admin`, since it is a boolean, becomes true).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add [*Projection*](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find) argument to `find` function:

```
var Manager = { 
  getUsers: function(callback){
    User.find({ admin : "false"}, {_id: 0, __v: 0, admin: 0, password: 0}, callback);
  },
```

and just pass your callback as third argument

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for